# Retrieving an array of [array of values] from an array of pandas dataframes as a numpy array [example inside]

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, data-science

I have a bunch of time series data (stocks) of the form :

```
      DateTime                  open    high    low close   volume
0     2017-01-02 09:15:00+05:30 8210.10 8211.70 8189.00 8189.55 0
1     2017-01-02 09:16:00+05:30 8188.75 8193.95 8188.75 8189.95 0
2     2017-01-02 09:17:00+05:30 8190.15 8190.75 8173.70 8173.70 0
....
38939 2017-06-01 15:01:00+05:30 9616.45 9617.30 9615.30 9615.85 0
```

I'm trying to group the data such that:

- Every 59 minutes of data go into a new array
- The 60th minute goes into a new array

The idea is that I will use every 59 minutes of data to predict the 60th minute of data. I have implemented code that  does this, however I don't think I've done it optimally because right now, I have an array of pandas dataframes for every 1:59 minute of data and a dataframe of every 60th minute. My result looks as follows for every 59 minute of data. It is a list of pandas dataframes called `predictors`:

```
[                    DateTime   open   high    low  close  volume
 0  2017-01-02 09:15:00+05:30  42.10  42.10  41.75  41.85    3650
 1  2017-01-02 09:16:00+05:30  41.85  41.95  41.75  41.95    1573
 2  2017-01-02 09:17:00+05:30  41.95  41.95  41.55  41.55     525
 3  2017-01-02 09:18:00+05:30  41.55  41.55  41.30  41.45    3938
 4  2017-01-02 09:19:00+05:30  41.45  41.60  41.45  41.60     320
 5  2017-01-02 09:20:00+05:30  41.60  41.60  41.60  41.60       0
 ...
 58 2017-01-02 10:13:00+05:30  41.25  41.25  41.25  41.25       0,
                      DateTime   open   high    low  close  volume
 60  2017-01-02 10:15:00+05:30  41.15  41.25  41.15  41.25     100
 61  2017-01-02 10:16:00+05:30  41.25  41.25  41.25  41.25       0
 62  2017-01-02 10:17:00+05:30  41.25  41.40  41.25  41.35    1623
...
 117  2017-01-02 10:23:00+05:30  41.60  41.60  41.60  41.60       0
 118  2017-01-02 10:24:00+05:30  41.60  41.60  41.40  41.40       9
... ]
```

and every 60th minute of data is a single dataframe called `predictee`:

```
DateTime    open    high    low close   volume
59  2017-01-02 10:14:00+05:30   41.25   41.25   41.15   41.15   2000
119 2017-01-02 11:14:00+05:30   41.15   41.15   41.15   41.15   0
179 2017-01-02 12:14:00+05:30   41.35   41.35   41.35   41.35   530
```

Now, I want to retrieve the 'close' from each pandas dataframe in the predictors list. Pseudocode for it will look right now look as follows

```
for each_df in predictors:
    closeCol = 'close' column as an numpy array
    append closeCol to a new array as an array
```

This will give me a new array of numpy arrays. However, this solution does not seem optimal and I'm wondering if I did something wrong or something can be done better. The question is: Is this the most optimal way to store the data in the format I want to get it in? If it is, is there a more optimal way to get only the close columns in the `predictors` array?

I know this is a long question so if any clarifications or details are needed, just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should be using `groupby`. Create a column 'hour' representing the hour like this:

```
hour_col = df[DateTime].apply(lambda x : datetime.datetime(year=x.year,month=x.month,day=x.day,hour=x.hour))

df_new = df.assign(hour = hour_col)
```

Then group by hour:

`groups = df_new.groupby('hour')`

The result is a groupby object from which you can access the dataframes for each hour. You can then look at the last minute in each group if you like.